# Using v-for to generate table rows, but I want to add a value to the row 'id' attribute

Tags: html, vue.js

I'm generating some table rows through view from data from Flask

```
<tr id="<% file.id %>" v-for="file in fileList">
  <td><img class="thumbnail_preview" src=""></td>
  <td><% file.filename %></td>
  <td><% file.extension %></td>
  <td><% file.mime %></td>
</tr>
```

I'm using `<% %>` as my delimiters because Flask/Jinja already uses `{{ }}`.

How can I set the `<tr>` id attribute while looping?

How can I also input a `file.path` into the img src as it too comes out as a string rather than a variable/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the bind syntax instead:

```
:id="file.id"
```

same for the image:

```
:src="file.src"
```

No need for mustache syntax.

Comment: I have a similar question to do with conditional classes if you'd happen to know the answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57230223/using-the-value-of-a-loop-on-v-for-to-set-a-conditional-class