# Using the value of a loop on v-for to set a conditional class

Tags: html, vue.js

I'm generating table rows using `v-for"x in y"`. I'd also like to set some classes conditional based on one of the values in the loop.

example:

```
<tr v-for="file in fileList" class="bg-green if file.include">
  <td><% file.filename %></td>
  <td><% file.extension %></td>
  <td><% file.mime %></td>
</tr>
```

If `file.include` is `true` I'd like the class `bg-green` applied, but its throwing an error.

note: Using custom delimiters as I'm using Flask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd just be:

```html
<tr v-for="file in fileList" :class="{'bg-green': file.include}">
```

`:class` is the shorthand form of `v-bind:class`. A binding is necessary to make the value an expression.

There are several ways to write the expression but in this case the simplest is to use the object form. The keys of the properties are the class names and the values are truthy/falsey values that determine whether or not to include that class name.

Alternatives include things like:

```html
<tr v-for="file in fileList" :class="file.include ? 'bg-green' : ''">
```

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html for more information.

Comment: I tried these and it was throwing a syntax error, so I had to manually do it with a jquery toggleClass, could it be because im using custom delimiters?

Comment: Looks like I must have done something wrong, I swear I copied the VueJS example exactly. Your version seems to work.